# rotation matrix with an abritrary rotation point

Tags: math, python-3.6, rotational-matrices

I need a rotation matrix that rotates a line about an abritrary point (its called center in the below mentioned code). I wrote a scrict but somewhere is a bug.
can you help me?
i put the center coordinates (abritrary center that replaces the origin) in the 4th column of rotational matrice. After plotting the results the line rotates about the axis, going through the origin, further on.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

f = lambda m,n: n+2*m
A = np.fromfunction(f, (10,3), dtype=int)

def get_rotation_matrix(center, x_rot: float, y_rot: float, z_rot: float, reverse=False):
    import numpy as np
    import math

    cx,sx = math.cos(x_rot),math.sin(x_rot)
    cy,sy = math.cos(y_rot),math.sin(y_rot)
    cz,sz = math.cos(z_rot),math.sin(z_rot)
    
    Rx = np.array(
        [[1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, cx, -sx, 0],
         [0, sx, cx, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]]
        )
    Ry = np.array(
        [[cy, 0, -sy, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0],
         [sy, 0, cy, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]]
        )
    Rz = np.array(
        [[cz, -sz, 0, 0],
         [sz, cz, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]]
        )
    T = np.array(
        [[1, 0, 0, center[0]],
         [0, 1, 0, center[1]],
         [0, 0, 1, center[2]],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]]
        )
    ret = T @ Rx @ Ry @ Rz
    print(ret)
    At = np.c_[A,np.ones(len(A))]
    k = np.dot(At,ret)
    print(k.T)
    
    return k #np.linalg.inv(ret) if reverse else ret 


theta_x = 5
theta_y = 0
theta_z = 0

k = get_rotation_matrix([0,0,10],theta_x/57.4,theta_y/57.4,theta_z/57.4)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot(k[:,0],k[:,1],k[:,2])
ax.plot(A[:,0],A[:,1],A[:,2])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to multiply by an additional matrix, the negative of the translation that you started with - to move the center point back to its original location, rather than leaving it relocated to the origin.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for feedback. It works.

Comment: ret = T @ Rx @ Ry @ Rz @ T2 @ At.T